# Three.js/ how to change colour of sections of imported object

Tags: three.js

I am asking this on behalf of a friend whose English is not so good. He is very technical so please feel free to be as technical as you want in your answer. The question is how to change colour in a portion of an imported 3D object. For example if we have an imported object that is a 3D car how can we change the colour of only the windows? Thanks for your help!

Comment: wouldn't it be more helpful to help your friend with his English instead? :-)

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if you helped me with my question ? If you can't help me that is fine...  I am not an English teacher either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported objects are like any others in THREE.js, so you can use the usual methods to alter properties, as long as you'
re not, say, repeatedly re-loading the model. So just iterate down the scene graph until you find the part you need (that is, recursively look at the `.children[]` arrays of various parts of the scene until you find the mesh(es) you want, unless you already have a direct reference).

Then for each mesh just call changes on the material properties, e.g. `mesh.material.color.set(0,1,0);` for some brilliant green.

Simple material changes will appear instantly. Complex ones like applying different materials or textures might require that you set the `needsUpdate` flag. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates to understand that.

Comment: Thanks Bjorke! We will try that!

Comment: Hi again Bjorke, we have a project with 3.js that requires personalisation but we have not managed to solve some parts to achieve want we need. Would it be possible for you to contact us via Twitter: @GrafosDesign  Thanks!